# Can i use operators in chr() funtion?

Tags: python

I'm writing a small program to convert all the ASCII lowercase characters in the range 97 to 122 into uppercase characters. I would like to do this without using the upper() function.

It works great if I'm just using one specific number in the chr() function, but as soon as I try to put in the range between (97 and 122) I get stuck. Is it possible at all to insert operators inside chr, or do I have to find another way of doing this?

```
    text = raw_input("Enter some text: ")

for character in text:
    if character == chr(>= 97 or <= 122):
        print chr(ord(character) - 32)
    else:
        print character
```

Thanks!

Comment: `chr()` returns a single character. What character do you think `>= 97 or <= 122` specifies?

Comment: You may want `if 97 <= ord(character) <= 122:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
if 97 <= ord(character) <= 122:
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest.